# how to render mysql data to jade file?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, pug

I'm using express ~4 and mysql to store the data.I'm able to create user database and user_info table . When I'm clicking on create button of signup page, the database is getting updated and i'm redirected to user-page which should render show.jade file containing user's information i.e email address and username. But it shows user is not defined. And the admin page that is locahost:3000/myusers shows the list of all users in the database as expected but its not showing the username

please help

app.js file in the root folder

> app.js file

```
    var express = require('express');

    var mysql = require('mysql');

    var path = require('path');

    var favicon = require('serve-favicon');

    var logger = require('morgan');

    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    var routes = require('./routes/index');

    var users = require('./routes/users');

    var app = express();
    // view engine setup

    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

    app.set('view engine', 'jade');

    app.use(logger('dev'));

    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

    app.use(cookieParser());

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    app.use('/', routes);

    app.use('/users', users);

    // mysql initialization

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({

            host     : 'localhost',

            user     : 'root',

            password : 'root',

            database : 'user'
        });

    // Database setup

    connection.query('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS user', function (err) {

        if (err) throw err;

        connection.query('USE user', function (err) {

            if (err) throw err;

            connection.query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_info('

                + 'email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,'

                + 'username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,'

                + 'PRIMARY KEY(username),'

                + 'password VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL'

                +  ')', function (err) {

                    if (err) throw err;

                });
        });

    });


    //index


     app.get("/myusers",function (req,res){

      connection.query('SELECT * from user_info',function (err,results){

        res.render('users/index',{users: results });

      });

     });


    //SIGNUP


    app.get("/myusers/signup",function (req,res){

      res.render('users/signup');

    });


    //CREate


    app.post("/myusers",function (req,res){

     var email = req.body.email;

     var userName = req.body.userName;

     var password = req.body.password;

     connection.query('INSERT INTO user_info (email, username, password) VALUES (?,

    ?, ?)', [email, userName, password], function(err, results) {

          if (err) res.json(err);

        res.redirect('/myusers/'+email);



    }) 

      });


    app.param('name',function(req,res,next,email){

      connection.query('SELECT * from user_info where email=?',[email],function 

    (err,row){

        if (err) res.json(err);

         req.user=row[0];


         next();

      });

     })

     //SHOW

    app.get('/myusers/:email',function(req,res){

     res.render("users/show",{user:req.user});


     });

    // catch 404 and forward to error handler


    app.use(function(req, res, next) {

      var err = new Error('Not Found');

      err.status = 404;

      next(err); 

    });



    // error handlers


    // development error handler

    // will print stacktrace

    if (app.get('env') === 'development') {

      app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {

        res.status(err.status || 500);

        res.render('error', {

          message: err.message,

          error: err

        });

      });

    }

    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {

      res.status(err.status || 500);

      res.render('error', {

        message: err.message,

        error: {}

      });

    });

    module.exports = app;
```

> index.jade file

---

index.jade file in views/user folder

```
    h1 All Users

    ul

     each user in users

       li: a(href="/myusers/#{user.email}") #{user.userName} (#{user.email})
```

> signup.jade file

---

index.signup file in views/user folder

```
    h1 new user

    form(method="POST" action="/myusers")

      table

        tr

          td User Email:

          td

            input#email(type="email", name="email")

        tr

          td Username:

          td

            input#userName(type="text", name="userName")

        tr

          td Password:

          td 

            input#password(type="password", name="password")

        tr

          td

            button(type="submit") Create
```

> show.jade file

---

show.signup file in views/user folder

```
    h1 #{user.email}

    ul

      li Email:#{user.email}

      li Username:#{user.usernName}
```

Comment: You call "alert(user)", when user doesn't seem to be defined anywhere. You probably was going to alert "req.user". Has req.user any data set in it?

Comment: still the same issue

Comment: connection.query('SELECT * from user_info set=?where email=?',[{req.user,email}],function 

    (err,row)

Comment: shall i do something like this, i'm new to this

Comment: If this variable is not set, you have to obtain the user in some way and then pass it into a jade template.

Comment: is my query with where clause is correct ?

Comment: What if ask your debugger? :)

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly (I was working on this about a month ago but currently don't have time to go and test your code), Jade has 2 formats for inserting variables depending on the situation:

1) The regular method of:

```
  li Email:#{user.email}

  li Username:#{user.usernName}
```

2) When dealing with quotes such as `li a(href="/myusers/#{user.email}")`, you have to do it slightly differently:

```
  li a(href="/myusers/"+user.email)
```

with no `#{}` but with a `+` and also **the variable must be outside the quotes**.

This is just one of the funky things with jade.

As an aside, I know 2) works because that's what I used. However, I'm not sure if you could use `li a(href="/myusers/"#{user.email})` with the regular `#{}` but outside the quotes.